# Order by logic and get mixed results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table structure

```
  id | status
-----+------+
1    | a    |
2    | b    |
3    | b    |
4    | b    |
5    | a    |
6    | a    |
7    | b    |
8    | a    |
```

I have two statuses "a" and "b".
I need to order this by logic that says this: for each two "a", show one "b".
So something like this (the "a" is more important, so if there are a lot of "b"s they will just be left in the end)

```
  id | status
-----+------+
1    | a    |
5    | a    |
2    | b    |

6    | a    |
8    | a    |
3    | b    |

4    | b    |
7    | b    |
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select      id
           ,status

from       (select      status
                       ,id
                       ,@prev_status := @status
                       ,@status      := status
                       ,@rn          := case when @prev_status = status 
                                             then @rn + 1 
                                             else 1 
                                        end           as rn

            from        mytable t1,(select @status:=null,@rn:=0) x

            order by    status
                       ,id
            ) t

 order by  floor((rn-1) / case status when 'a' then 2 else 1 end)         
          ,case status when 'a' then 1 else 2 end  
          ,rn
;
```

---

```
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
|  1 | a      |
|  5 | a      |
|  2 | b      |
|  6 | a      |
|  8 | a      |
|  3 | b      |
|  4 | b      |
|  7 | b      |
+----+--------+
```

**This will help you to understand the solution:**
(group_id = `floor((rn-1) / case status when 'a' then 2 else 1 end)`)

```
+--------+----+----+----------+
| status | id | rn | group_id |
+--------+----+----+----------+
| a      |  1 |  1 |        0 |
| a      |  5 |  2 |        0 |
| a      |  6 |  3 |        1 |
| a      |  8 |  4 |        1 |
| b      |  2 |  1 |        0 |
| b      |  3 |  2 |        1 |
| b      |  4 |  3 |        2 |
| b      |  7 |  4 |        3 |
+--------+----+----+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Though it appears to be very slow, I mean, I tried it on table with 20k records, and it was running for few minutes.. eventually I needed to kill it

Comment: The ripoff Gordon did to my answef will probably work faster

Comment: Thanks, eventually your answer helped to complete the answer by Gordon :)

Comment: Tested on 1M records, took few seconds.

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: I tried your updated query, it's even faster than @GordonLinoff 's answer, thanks! I marked your message as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use variables to enumerate the values and then some simple logic:

```
select id, status
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@s = status, @rn + 1,
                        if(@s := status, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @s := '') params
      where status in ('a', 'b')
      order by status, id
     ) ab
order by (case when status = a then floor( (rn - 1) / 2) else (rn - 1) end),
         status, id;
```

Comment: This should be the fastest method in MySQL.  It is also clearer to me than correlated subqueries, but I admit to a certain familiarity with variables in MySQL.

Comment: I think this is the first time I see you using variables to generate row numbers. As I recall, you always use correlated sub-queries :-)

Comment: Thanks! this solution actually works pretty good. Though I have a little problem with it, I get an extra "a" in the first group: "a a a b a a b a a b"

Comment: Ok was able to solve the above issue by using the "order by" login from @DuduMarkovitz 's answer. `order by floor((rn-1) / case status when 'a' then 2 else 1 end)`